# add_filter('the_content') does not return as expected if another function called inside the call back function

Tags: wordpress

Why the  `<div>Ad goes here` part is showing on top of content? It is supposed to show on the bottom of the `$content`. If i return `$content` directly as `return $content.'<div>The ads goes here</div>';`, it shows in the bottom. Any clues?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'ads_filter' );

function ads_filter ($content){
     return $content.ads();
 }

function ads(){
   echo '<div>The ads goes here</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple solution use `return` instead of `echo` in your `ads()` function:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'ads_filter' );

function ads_filter ($content){
     return $content.ads();
 }

function ads(){
   return '<div>The ads goes here</div>';
}
```

Because when you write `echo` and concatenate it with `$content` at the time it already prints the external content and then the actual post content is concatenated.

Here is your answer for the shortcode:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'ads_filter' );

function ads_filter ($content){
     return $content.do_shortcode(ads());
 }
add_shortcode('ads_shortcode','here_is_func');
function here_is_func(){
    return '<div>The ads goes here</div>';
}
function ads(){
   return '[ads_shortcode]';
}
```

Comment: I need to use do_shortcode on the return value of ads() function... How is it possible?

Comment: The  function here_is_func that you wrote in the above example is a bit more complex in my actual case. I rather prefer to echo directly because it will be difficult to return as some javascript is embedded in it. I Hope you can understand.

Comment: Yes I understand and we can also return javascript but it looks ridiculous :)

Answer (score 2):

If you see the signature of `add_filter` function from the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)

```
add_filter( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

You can just play with it by changing the different priorities.  Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action. Just give it a high priority and see where it is placed.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'ads_filter', 10 );

function ads_filter ($content){
     return $content.ads();
 }

function ads(){
   echo '<div>The ads goes here</div>';
}
```